# Why do I get a verification error when trying to upload my code to my Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, atom-editor, platformio

I am building an Arduino car, which avoids obstacles and when I try to upload the code to my Arduino from the PlatformIO package of Atom I get an error message like this:

*avrdude:* *verifying* ...
*avrdude:* *verification* *error,* *first* *mismatch* *at* *byte* *0x0aaa*
         *0x68* *!= 0x60*
*avrdude:* *verification* *error;* *content* *mismatch*

*avrdude* *done.*  *Thank you.*

This started happening a few days ago for no reason. It worked perfectly and suddenly I started getting this error message.

My code is:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Servo.h>

const int trigPin = 6;
const int echoPin = 7;
const int motorRF = 3;
const int sleep = 4;
const int motorRB = 9;
const int motorLF = 10;
const int motorLB = 11;

int minDistance = 350;
long value;
int speed = 1000;
int randNum;

void setup() {
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

    pinMode(motorRF, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorRB, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorLF, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorLB, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(sleep, OUTPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
}

//Define the directions of the motors
void forward() {
    analogWrite(motorRF, speed);
    analogWrite(motorLF, speed);
    analogWrite(motorRB, 0);
    analogWrite(motorLB, 0);
}
void backward() {
    analogWrite(motorRF, 0);
    analogWrite(motorLF, 0);
    analogWrite(motorRB, speed);
    analogWrite(motorLB, speed);
}
void right() {
    analogWrite(motorRF, 0);
    analogWrite(motorLF, speed);
    analogWrite(motorRB, speed);
    analogWrite(motorLB, 0);
}
void left() {
    analogWrite(motorRF, speed);
    analogWrite(motorLF, 0);
    analogWrite(motorRB, 0);
    analogWrite(motorLB, speed);
}

void loop() {
//Ultrasonic sensor
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(5);

    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    value = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Value = "); Serial.println(value);

    delay(50);

//Motors
    digitalWrite(sleep, HIGH);
    if(value > minDistance) {
    //Drive forward
        backward();
    }
    else {
    //Drive backward
        forward();
        delay(1000);

    //Pick between number 1 and 2
        randNum = random(0, 2);
        Serial.println("Random Num = "); Serial.println(randNum);

    //If the number is 2 then drive right
        if(randNum == 1) {
            right();
            delay(500);
        }
    //Else drive left
        else {
            left();
            delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This feels like a hardware problem. Does the problem happen when you use a different Arduino?

Comment: After doing some research I had the same thought. I ordered some new Arduinos to see if it is a hardware problem (they have not arrived yet). I will tell you if I have the same problem with them. Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a hardware problem. The program is fine. I tried to upload it to another Arduino and it worked perfectly. Thank you.